# Expand a RDD[List[(ImmutableBytesWritable, Put)]] to RDD[(ImmutableBytesWritable, Put)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD whose each element is List

aRDD =List[(List[(key1, value1), (key2, value2)], List[(key3, value3)]]

Now my aim is to write this RDD to HBase using **aRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(job.getConfiguration())**, but the problem is that **aRDD** should be converted to **(key,pair)** value. 
Hence I need to convert aRDD to

aRDD = [(key1, value1), (key2, value2) , (key3, value3)].

How to do the above process in scala?

**EDIT**:- I want to get a list of tuples from the List of Lists of tuple.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't want to make (key1,value1,key2.value2.key3,value3) but ((key1, value1), (key2, value2) , (key3, value3))

Comment: Here you go: `List(List((1, 2), (3, 4)), List((5, 6))).flatten` will produce `List((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))`